# Extend platformConfig property of Ext.form.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to overide a global platformConfig of a Ext.form.Panel class.

I'm trying to do this to avoid defining the same platFormConfig on every view that is extending Ext.form.Panel. I'm trying to avoid to create a intermediate baseclass like My.form.Panel just for adding a platformConfig property.

What I've tried so far:

```
Ext.form.Panel.addMember('platformConfig',  [{
        platform: ['windows'],
        scrollable: 'vertical'
}]);
```

But this doesn't apply to the inherited view classes. Is there a clean solution for extending a Ext/Sencha base class?

Thanks in advance - any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to override, I would use `override`:

```
Ext.define('MyOverride',{
    override:'Ext.form.Panel', // <- this is an override!
    platformConfig:{
        ...
    }
});
```

The override definition should take place either in Ext.onReady or in the application `init` method.

This would then apply to inherited view classes as well - unless the platformConfig is overridden there again.

Comment: thanks, but so I need to change all my classes to extend 'MyOverride'? That's what I wanted to avoid. Isn't there a way to change standard classes?

Comment: No, the `myOverride` string won't be used anywhere else. The platformConfig will be part of `Ext.form.Panel`. That's how `override:` differs from `extends:`

Comment: thanks thisworked, but it isn't processed by the framework. the key is on the component, but the views are not rendered with given platformConfig. If I change the component on sencha-touch source directly it works as expected